# Using powershell to batch convert docx to pdf

Tags: powershell, pdf, ms-word

I'm attempting to use powershell to batch convert a lot of docx into pdf, into a different directory while maintaining the folder structure of the root.

I have the script working, however around 1 out of every 10 documents word pops up a "SaveAs" dialog, which i do not understand prompting me to save the docx file, although i have visible set to false.

```
#Stage the files
$sourceDir = "C:\Documents\"
$targetDir = "C:\Temp_Stage\"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -filter "*.doc?" -recurse |  foreach{ 
    $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length); 
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;  
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile 
} 

#Convert the files
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$folderpath = "c:\Temp_Stage\*"
$fileTypes = "*.docx","*doc"

Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -include $fileTypes -Recurse |
foreach-object {
 $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
 $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
 $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
 $doc.close()
 }
 $word.Quit()
```

Is there a way to suppress all word dialogs / warning / errors it should be a fairly automatic process that has ended up being pretty manual process.

Comment: Can you print your variables ? Maybe there's an error with $path / $_.fullname or $wdFormatPDF for the files that file and that make the dialog popup.

Comment: Another thing to consider, when you say around 1/10 documents, are they always the same or is it random documents everytime ?

Comment: It appears to be both -- the same, and random, the documents are pulled from a sharepoint lib, and then converted. If i re-run the same documents, ill get the same errors, if i pull fresh from sharepoint, ill get different ones. It must be a document issue, but I'm not sure how to track down the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you should pause between the Word-COM commands.
I also had to write a script that Word converts the documents from. dot to. dotm.
Not only did I occasionally get the save dialog, but also a lot of E_FAIL errors in the console.
The breaks (maximum 50ms) helped a lot.
Break in Powershell:

```
Start-Sleep -m 50
```

I hope it will help you.

Greetings
Bloodrayne1995

Comment: This did help a bit. Thanks. Did it solve your save dialog completely, or just lessen it? It did not totally eliminate it for me...